# VBA - Extract Date/Time from Unique TextBox/Drop Down Calendar

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using VBA to try to scrape a time/date from a website. The item I'm trying to extract it from is a text box that leads to a drop down calendar. Inside of the text box I can see and select the text I want to extract. Here is the HTML:

```
<input type="text" date-begin="ac.Start" date-end="ac.Finish" ng-model="Data.estRange" ng-change="updateDuration()" size="45" style="display:inline;" name="estRange" id="estRange" value="" rangepicker="" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-date-range">
```

Inside of the text box it says, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm PM - mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm PM".

When I try to grab the inner text nothing gets returned. Here is an example of the code I tried to use:

```
        Set objinputs = aExplorer.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
        For Each ele In objinputs
            If ele.TagName Like "date-end" Then
            cTestScrape = ele.innertext
            End If
        Next
        Do While aExplorer.Busy
            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 10, Now)
        Loop
```

Any ideas on how to do this correctly? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried ele.Value?

Comment: Thank you very much Sorceri! This worked! Why did it work considering that the html code lists .value as ""? I believed value contained nothing accordingly. How is it grabbing anything from that empty string?

Comment: It is most likely being set via javascript

Comment: Interesting, didn't realize that was a possibility. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Per Sorceri (thanks!),

Even though the ele.Value string is listed as blank in the HTML, pulling the .value data correctly pulled in the date/time listed with one additional modification to the code (changing the ele.tagname). Here is the correct code.

```
            Set objinputs = aExplorer.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
        For Each ele In objinputs
            If ele.Name Like "estRange" Then
            cTestScrape4 = ele.Value
            End If
        Next
        Do While aExplorer.Busy
            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 10, Now)
        Loop
```